# Cypress: can't log in in the Cypress browser

Tags: cypress

I'm trying to set up E2E testing of a Vue application with Cypress.

I can log into the app with my regular Chrome browser. However, the browser opened up by Chrome won't let me log in. Both the automatic login via Cypress and manual login fail.

Is there a setting I'm missing?

My Vue element:

```
<template>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">

            <div class="field is-horizontal">
                <div class="field-label is-normal">
                    <label class="label">Username</label>
                </div>
                <div class="field-body">
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="control">
                            <input v-model="username" class="input" type="text"
                                   placeholder="Your username">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field is-horizontal">
                <div class="field-label is-normal">
                    <label class="label">Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="field-body">
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="control">
                            <input v-model="password" class="input" type="password"
                                   placeholder="Your password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field is-horizontal">
                <div class="field-label">
                    <!-- Left empty for spacing -->
                </div>
                <div class="field-body">
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="control text-center">
                            <button v-on:click="login()" class="button is-primary">
                                Login
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

My test file:

```
describe('Logging in', () => {
    it('Logs in as admin', () => {
        cy.visit('/')
            .get('input[type="text"]')
            .type('Admin')
            .get('input[type="password"]')
            .type('Pass1234')
            .get('button').click()
            .location().should((loc) => {
            expect(loc.pathname).to.eq('/dashboard-main/dashboard');
        })
    })
})
```

Update: some suggestions here: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1759#issuecomment-391729559

Comment: In cypress.json you can use {...,"chromeWebSecurity": false} to disable cross-origin errors

Comment: @Boris Did u figure out what went wrong? I too have similar issue. In Chrome browser opened by Cypress, one of my functionality is behaving weird even when I do manually. However in regular Chrome browser it works perfect

Comment: @Aish see update

Answer (score 1):

Do you get to see anything during the e2e test when it runs? Like Cypress typing in that fields?

Besides the fact that I wouldn't use very generic locators, I would stop in the `.click()` and then check the new path with `cy.url()`